# How to display the meta description information using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a large website where I want to easily verify if a meta description has been added and to be sure it is correct.

I created a little button that will show up on the front end of each page. I wrote a little jQuery to put up an alert box that displays the meta description.

HTML

```
 <div id="getmeta"></div>
```

jQuery

```
var thisDesc;
$("#getmeta").click(function() {
    thisDesc = $('meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
    alert(thisDesc);
});
```

When I try this, the alert box just displays "undefined". I have verified that my test page does indeed have content within the meta description.

Any suggestions?

I did research this and I repeatedly found the code that I am using.

Comment: If the code isn't working then I suggest that your HTML may be invalid. Please show what you are using...

Comment: I am waiting for the document to be ready and this is the meta description (shortened a bit) <meta content="Walk Ride U.S.A. has maps ...." name="description">

Comment: I got this to work by adding a $ in front of the variable name - saw it on jsfiddle.

Comment: You need to show the least amount of code that shows your problem. Please edit your question to show this.